# リンクの色がバックグラウンドと被って変えたい

Tags: css

リンクの色がバックグラウンドと被って変えたいです。
以下で `color:skyblue` になりません。答えていただける方よろしくお願いします。

```html
<a style="color:skyblue;" 
href="https://www.salk.edu/">Sark Institute for Biological Studies ソーク研究所Hello World!===");<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

まずは`</a>`でタグを閉じてみてください。

```
<a style="color:skyblue;" href="...">...</a>
```